# Light sensor sensitivity for use in camera application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sensors, mjpeg, light-sensor

I am working on an application to record video automatically at remote, outdoor locations using MJPEG format. I would like to stop video recording at night when light levels are below the required threshold. To do this I've used the following to set a flag that starts and stops recording.

```
boolean bTooDarkFlag;
float fLightLevel;

if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
        fLightLevel = event.values[0];
        if (fLightLevel > 0.1){
            bTooDarkFlag = false;    
        }else{
            bTooDarkFlag = true;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, the sensor reaches 0.0 while there is still just enough light to record with. What other solutions might be worth exploring? Can I crank up the sensitivity of the light sensor? Part of this problem is that the sensor on the device that I may deploy to (Samsung S4 Active) is on the opposite side as the camera, therefore potentially in the shadow. Thoughts on using camera input to set/reset the boolean flag? Thanks in advance...

Comment: 1. Sample the camera image for some percentage of black pixels. 2. Use the location/date to calculate when is sunrise and sunset and trigger off of that.

Comment: Suggestion #1 is a possibility. Suggestion #2 would need to take into account local topography. Application will be used in mountainous areas where actual horizon azimuth will be varied relative to the theoretical (flat) horizon. Additional snow cover + trees of varying albedo add further complexity to #2. Thanks.